# How can I open georeferenced ArcMap raster files in Qgis?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

How can I open georeferenced arcmap raster files in Qgis?

Comment: Welcome to our site! Please consult our [faq] and then follow its directions for (a) searching our site for existing answers to your question and then, if you do not find any, (b) formulating a *new* question in a *new* thread.
Please note that a good question is expected to include proof of basic research effort.

Answer (score 4):

You will find support for an amazing amount of raster formats in QGIS, all of which are made possible by GDAL.  If you are referring to the Arc/Info Binary Grid format, yes there is support for that format too.

[image]

[image]